# DIY Alphabet and Number-shaped Cereal

Tags: baking, cereal

Out of curiosity, is there a way to recreate alpha-bits cereal and number-shaped cereal from scratch at home? I want to make the cereal in these flavors: Plain, Frosted, Cocoa, Cinnamon-Brown Sugar and Fruity.

Comment: What research have you done so far? Why weren't the results satisfactory?

Comment: It's not possible to make these 2 cereals but I refuse to give up. There has to be a way to make alpha-bits and number-shaped cereal from scratch at home. I don't find the results satisfactory because I believe we're not over the limits on home cereal making yet.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to recreate? I suspect that it is puffed cereal, and then the answer is indeed that no, you can't do it at home. If that's unsatisfactory to you, you can look into patents for machines for cereal expansion and consider what would take you to build a functioning one.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate alpha-bits cereal and number-shaped cereal from scratch at home. Should I treat alphabet and number cookies as alpha-bits & number-shaped cereal?